# How can I rewrite this a generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following piece of code:

```
 public Component GetComponent(Type type)
    {
        return Components.FirstOrDefault(component => component.GetType() == type);
    }
```

The caller has to do a nasty cast to get the component it passed in - how can I rewrite this to a cast-less generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you can move the cast inside the function and do it this way.

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
{
    return (T)Components.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetType() == typeof(T));
}
```

If the type is not known at compile time going in to the function (like, say `GetComponet()` is called in a loop where the type is passed in as a argument) there is no way to get a strongly typed object back.

Comment: The type is indeed known at compile-time.

Comment: Just as a programmers note: The `where` clause is not necessary for the code to function, but it does help you from accidentally passing in a type that is not derived from Component and would never be held inside the components collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Component GetComponent<T>() where T : Component{
    var type = typeof(T);
    return Components.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```